# How to hide div present in master page on dashboard page load in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, css

I have a master page in which i have a div like

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="NGO_MS.SiteMaster" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" 
   src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="container">
      <div>
        <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse " id="menu">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right alert-success">
            <li class="active"><a href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/> 
    </div>
    <div class="container" style="background-color: white">
         <div>
        <div style="float: left; color: green"> 
        </div>
        <div style="float: right; color: green">
        </div>
     </div> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In dashboard.aspx i want to hide div with id menu which is present in master page.. some thing like this ..

```
        <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="dashboard.aspx.cs" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" Inherits="NGO_MS.dashboard" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="UC_LeftMenu" TagName="LeftMenu" Src="UserControls/UC_LeftMenu.ascx" %>
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
           $('#menu').hide();
       });
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<form runat="server" ID="Form1">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
       <div class="col-md-10">
           <UC_LeftMenu:LeftMenu ID="LeftMenu" runat="server" />
            <div class="col-md-9">
               <%--dashboard content will go here --%>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>   
</asp:Content>
```

How can I fix this its not working. Thankyou :) 
I am using update panel in dashboard but this update panel is not wrapping div with id menu. How i can resolve this.

Comment: Are you actually calling `pageLoad()` somewhere on your page? Defining a function doesn't execute the code within it.

Comment: I actually dont know how to get it done i just tried pageLoad(). can you suggest me anything else how can i get the solution ? @Brian Driscoll

Answer (score 3):

You need **ScriptManager** if you want to call **pageLoad**.

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager1" />
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad() {
        $('#menu').hide();
    }
</script>
```

Since you are using jQuery, you can use the following -

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
   src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#menu').hide();
    });
</script>
```

### Another Approach using Server Side Code

You can create **Menu** as **Server Control**, and access it from **dashboard** codebehind.

### Site.Master

```
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="MenuPanel" 
                CssClass="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right alert-success">
                    <li class="active"><a href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
                </ul>
            </asp:Panel>
        </div>
    </div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
</div>
```

### Site.Master.cs

```
public partial class Site : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    public bool MenuPanelVisible
    {
        set { MenuPanel.Visible = value; }
    }
}
```

### dashboard.aspx.cs

```
public partial class dashboard : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var master = Master as Site;
        if (master != null)
        {
            master.MenuPanelVisible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i am using update panel and your suggesion is not working. i am using update panel in dashboard pae is that causing problem ?

Comment: i have tried these option i am using update panel in dashboard and that update panel is not wrapping div with id menu. @Win how can i solve this

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your code, it is hard to say which part causes the problem. Please upload the code ***(as small as possible)*** so that we can replicate the issue.

Comment: I have edited the dashboard part code where i am using the update panel

Comment: i have added almost the complete part .. kindly guide me :)

Comment: Your last posted code work.s It might be that you have JavaScript error in other places. As the result, it'll stop run the menu hide function. Another problem I found is **form tag** should be outside of other controls in **master page**. It should be `<body><form runat="server">.....</form></body>`

Answer (score 0):

check your HTML. if i am not mistaken, the ID will not be generated to HTML 1:1.

also currently your JS will not be executed... on the other hand you can define server-sided code too:

```
<script language="C#" runat="server" type="text/c#">
     public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
         //hide the menu here
     }
</script>
```

alternatively you could even do the following:

```
<div id="menu" onload="this.visibility=hidden;"></div>
```

Comment: id is being generated. i am using update panel in dashboard but its not wrapping div with id menu. how can i resolve this?

Comment: @Afnan what do you mean div with id menu is not wrapped??

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your pageLoad functionality in the jQuery document ready handler so it executes after the DOM has loaded.

It should look something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#menu').hide();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: tried this but not working i have update panel in dashboard page . is that causing problem @Becuzz

Comment: this is jQuery code... you will need to include the jQuery library for this to work

Comment: @AfnanAhmad Maybe, depends where the UpdatePanel is and if it is wrapping the menu div.

Comment: @Vogel612 not working as i mentioned i am using update panel .. library is already included ..

Comment: update panel is in the dashboard and its not wrapping the div with id menu @Becuzz